# Get substring in one column based on the value in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a12','b1','c'],'Length':[2,1,0]})
test_df

    Length  name
0   2   a12
1   1   b1
2   0   c
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
    Length  name
0   2   a
1   1   b
2   0   c
```

With this code: [Getting substring based on another column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767787/getting-substring-based-on-another-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

```
test_df.apply(lambda x: x['name'][:-x['Length']],axis = 1)
test_df
```

I got the same dataframe than before

```
    Length  name
0   2   a12
1   1   b1
2   0   c
```

Comment: How does it work? What are you trying to do? Can you explain this a little differently?

Comment: I'm trying to remove the number in the end of each element in the name column

Comment: You need to assign back the result, `apply` isn't inplace `test_df['name'] = test_df.apply(lambda x: x['name'][:-x['Length_to_drop']], axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, it wokred thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `apply` a bit, to slice with respect to `len(x['name'])` -

```
def f(x):
    return x['name'][:len(x['name']) - x['Length_to_drop']]

df.apply(f, 1)

0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a12','b1','c'],'Length':[2,1,0]})
test_df['name']=test_df.apply(lambda x: x['name'][:len(x['name'])-x['Length']],axis = 1)
test_df
```

This will output as you intended

```
   Length name
0       2    a
1       1    b
2       0    c
```

Answer (score -1):

One can use list functions for this:

```
outlist = list(map(lambda x,y: x[0:(len(x)-y)], test_df.name, test_df.Length_to_drop))
test_df.name = outlist
print(test_df)
```

Output:

```
   Length_to_drop name
0               2    a
1               1    b
2               0    c
```