# Python, split column of strings at positions specified in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"strings":["stackoverflow", "stackexchange"], "start":[3, 4], "end": [7, 9]})
```

I want to split the `strings` column at `start` and `end` positions.

```
df1['strings'].str[df1['start']:df1['end']]
```

gives me `NaN`.

I managed to get the result this way, but it doesn't seem optimal.

```
[df1['strings'].str[i:j] for i, j in zip(df1['start'], df1['end'])][:1]
```

Comment: What you have is one of the most optimal way IMO since you have a string column and also you have 2 slicer columns. The `.str` method is quite slow in pandas , may be include the `strings` column in the zip as well

Comment: @anky thanks, this [k[i:j] for i, j, k in zip(df1['start'], df1['end'], df1['strings'])] ?

Comment: yes , I was testing `[a[b:c] for a,b,c in zip(*(df1.get(col) for col in ['strings', 'start', 'end']))]` :) same almost. Also you can use `apply` but it is slower

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to vectorize this - the best you can do is row-wise function application.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"strings":["stackoverflow", "stackexchange"], "start":[3, 4], "end": [7, 9]})
df1['strings'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['strings'][x["start"]:x["end"]], axis=1)
```

See also: [Get substring in one column based on the value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203449/get-substring-in-one-column-based-on-the-value-in-another-column)

Note that your example is not quite correct - you're taking the start and end values from a particular row and applying them to every row.

Answer (score 0):

one way is this

```
    for _, row in df1.iterrows():
        print(row['strings'][row['start']:row['end']])
```